# Adding additional data to Kendo UI Context Menu items

Tags: javascript, angular, kendo-ui, kendo-contextmenu

I want to utilize the Kendo UI Context Menu in my app. I was expecting the standard behavior of having text displayed in the menu itself but a different value (an ID or key) being returned to the `select` event handler.

For instance, the menu displays a list of names but when I click on one of them, I get the ID associated with the name.

I've tried adding additional properties besides `text` to the array of items in the context menu but I don't see them on the event object in the handler.

I can't use the text to find the appropriate id that matches it since there could be entries with the same text but different IDs.

Any ideas?

**Edit:**

Currently I build the context menu like this:

```
open: (e) => {
    let itemKeys = [1, 2, 3];

    let menu = e.sender;
    menu.remove(".context-menu-item");
    menu.append(itemKeys.map((itemKey) => {
        return {
            text: "<div data-item-key='" + itemKey + "'>Test Text</div>",
            cssClass: "context-menu-item",
            encoded: false
        };
    }));
}
```

While this solution does satisfy my needs, it adds an extra element to the DOM which, while being insignificant, isn't perfect...

Comment: This question, more than a year old, has just been down-voted. Could the down-voter explain why?

Comment: I tried to upvote it but everything is inverted in Australia down under

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's undocumented, but `ContextMenu` actually inherits from [`Menu`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/menu). Therefore, all options of `Menu` are available. In particular, you can add an `attr` object to your data items, cf the [example in the documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/menu/configuration/datasource).

To complete your example:

```
open: (e) => {
    let itemKeys = [1, 2, 3];

    let menu = e.sender;
    menu.remove(".context-menu-item");
    menu.append(itemKeys.map((itemKey) => {
        return {
            text: "Test Text",
            cssClass: "context-menu-item",
            // add whatever attribute
            attr: {
                'data-item-key': itemKey
            }
        };
    }));
}
```

Then, in your `select` handler:

```
select: (e) => {
    console.log($(e.item).data('item-key'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Do you happen to know when this option was added? I think I might have tried it a year ago and it didn't work...
Anyway, I preferred avoiding another jQuery call so I used `attr: {"item-key": itemKey}` and `e.item.getAttribute("item-key")`.

Comment: Based on my tests, it appeared in version `2016.2.504` (was not present in `2016.1.112`).

Answer (score 1):

Option 1)
You might add a data that will specify your Id.
I made this with mvc wrapper but it can be done with pure javascript as well.

```
@(Html.Kendo()
    .ContextMenu()
    .Name("contextMenuGridTicketTestiMessaggi")
    .Target("#gridTicketTestiMessaggi")
    .Filter("tr")
    .Orientation(ContextMenuOrientation.Vertical)
    .Items(items =>
    {
        items.Add().Text("Update").HtmlAttributes(new { data_toggle = "update" });
        items.Add().Text("Save").HtmlAttributes(new { data_toggle = "save" });
        items.Add().Text("Delete").HtmlAttributes(new { data_toggle = "delete" });
    })
    .Events(e => {
        e.Select("contextMenuGridTicketTestiMessaggiSelect"); 
    }));

    var contextMenuGridTicketTestiMessaggiSelect = function(e) {
        var action = $(e.item).data("toggle");
        var that = this;
        if (action === "update") {}
    ...
```

Option 2) You might define with every item(throught html content) a function to be called in each onClick event for the specific item.

```
items.Add().Encoded(false).Text("<span onclick='update()'>Update</span>");
items.Add().Encoded(false).Text("<span onclick='delete()'>Delete</span>");
...
```

### Update

```
<div id="target">Target</div>
<ul id="context-menu"></div>
<script>
    $("#context-menu").kendoContextMenu({
        target: "#target",
        open: function(e) {
            let itemKeys = [1, 2, 3];

            let menu = e.sender;                 
            menu.remove(".context-menu-item");
            menu.setOptions({
                dataSource: itemKeys.map((itemKey) => {
                    return {
                        text: "<div data-item-key='" + itemKey + "' style='white-space: nowrap'>Test Text</div>",
                        cssClass: "context-menu-item",
                        encoded: false
                    };
                })
            });
        },
        select: function(e) {
           console.log($($(e.item).find("div")[0]).data("item-key"))                      
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer.
**Option 1**: this is exactly what I want to do but there is no way to add HTML attributes to items when using the Kendo UI ContextMenu widget, at least as far as I know.
**Option 2**: In my current solution I do something similar to what you suggested but instead of supplying a function, I enter my extra data in an attribute in the inner element and extract it in the `select` event.

Comment: You are welcome.
I used those solutions in the current MVC project i'm working on and both works. Those solutions don't satisfy my obsession for clear code but i don't think it can be done in a better way.

Comment: The problem is that they're working in MVC but the first option isn't available in the JS Kendo UI and I have a better solution than the second one...

Comment: I tried first solution and works with js as well as long as you define data attributes in the list item definition:
<div id="target">Target</div>
<ul id="context-menu">
    <li data-yxn = 'x'>Item 1</li>    
</ul>
<script>
    $("#context-menu").kendoContextMenu({
        target: "#target",
        animation: {
            close: {
                effects: "slideIn:up"
            }
        },
        select: function(e){
          console.log($(e.item).data("yxn"));
      }
    });
</script>

Comment: It's not totally clear from my original question but I set the items dynamically and not in the HTML.

Comment: Can you post the code otherwhise it's hard to help?

Comment: I added my current code to the original question above.

Comment: Does menu.setOptions fix the issue?

Comment: `setOptions` allows setting any of the fields of the `ContextMenuOptions` object of the context menu. This allows me to set the `dataSource` field and the items of the context menu but I can't add additional data to the items in this manner either.

Comment: Unfortunately no, only few properties are available throught setOptions which are considered in the items creation in the DOM.